# Plotting fitted values vs observed ones in R or winbugs

Tags: r, plot, line, winbugs

I want to plot the fitted values versus the observed ones and want to put straight line showing the goodness of fit. However, I do not want to use `abline()` because I did not calculate the fitted values using `lm` command as my I used a model that `R` does not cover. I calculated the coefficients and used them to calculate the fitted values. So, what can I do to obtain such a plot in R or in winbugs?

Here is what I want

[image]

Comment: I could not find anything important

Comment: What do you know of the line? Intercept and slope would call for `abline`. Two points call for computation of intercept and slope, and then using `abline`. What else may be there?

Comment: My linear model is one-way error components random effects model whose specification is y_i = 1 - xbeta + delta_i + e_i where x is the design matrix, beta is the vector of the regression coefficients, delta_i is the i-th random effect, e is the i-th usual error. I obtained the likelihood for this model and then obtained the betas by using optim in R and then the fitted values. Also note that there is no intercept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still no data provided, but maybe this simple example using the `curve` function will inform the process:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 2+ 3*(1:10) + rnorm(10)
plot(1:10, y)
curve( 2+3*x, 0, 10,  add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Note to new R users. the expression `y_i = 1 - xbeta + delta_i + e_i` would fail in R in part because the x and beta are not separated by an operator. But if you do understand R's matrix syntax it might be a very compact expression even if "X" were multidimensional. All of htis depends on the specifics which we are so far lacking.

Comment: Brilliant idea Dwin. Thank you